# Probability of getting $Y$ dice showing at least $Z$ when rolling $X$ regular dice?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Roll $X$ regular $6$-sided dice.
>
> What are the odds to get $Y$ dices showing a value of $Z$ or more if
>   I reroll all dice that are below $Z$ one more time?

Example:

I'm given $8$ dice and want to have $7$ dice showing $5$ or more.

For all that are below $5$ after the first roll, I re-roll them.

What is the probability of getting $7$ out of $8$ dice with a value of $5$ or more after the reroll?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange! Have you tried anything by yourself so far? Also, I'm assuming that you always choose to reroll all the dice that aren't a success, otherwise we would have a fourth variable, is that correct?

Comment: http://anydice.com/ is a great resource for exploring questions like this.

Comment: Vepir, I have already figured out the probabilities of rolling X regular 6-sided dice and having Y dice show a value of Z or more. I just can't figure out the re-rolling aspect of it. And yes, we are assuming you would always re-roll a die below Z value.